# Почему не работают "двунаправленные вычисляемые свойства"?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть такой компонент:(inputTextApp)

```js
<template>
  <input class="input_text_1" :placeholder="placeholder_text" :value="input_value"/>
</template>


<script>

  export default{

    props:['placeholder_text', 'input_value'],
  }

</script>
```

И его подключение в другой, более глобальный компонент:

```
<div class="input_wrap">

    <InputTextApp class="phone_number" placeholder_text="+49" v-model="message">
    </InputTextApp>

</div>

<script>
import InputTextApp from '~/components/FormElements/InputTextApp';

  export default{

  components:{
    InputTextApp,
  },

  computed: {

    message: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.tracker.trackingClientData.loading_cell_phone_number;
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$store.commit('tracker/setTrackingClientData_loading_cell_phone_number', value);
      }
    }

}

}
</script>
```

Vuex хранилище(tracker.js) для данной страницы выглядит следующим образом:

const axios = require("axios");

export const state = () => ({

```
trackingClientData: {
    "loading_cell_phone_number": "777777",
}
```

});

export const mutations = {

```
setTrackingClientData_loading_cell_phone_number (state, loadingCellPhoneNumber) {
    state.trackingClientData.loading_cell_phone_number = loadingCellPhoneNumber;
},
```

};

Вопрос: 
В данной конструкции я пытался реализовать двунаправленное вычисляемое свойство, описанное в документации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Которое в моем случае почему то не работает.
В Vue дебаггере можно увидеть следующую картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самом поле инпута никакого значения(777777, в отличии от дебаггера) не наблюдается. Ввод в поле инпута каких бы то ни было символов - также не дает никакой реакции - ни в дебаггере ни где бы то ни было еще.

Почему это происходит и что я упустил из виду?

Comment: v-model, по дефолту следит за полем `value` и подписывается на событие `input`. Ваш компонент inputTextApp - не имеет нужного поля и не эммитит нужное событие. Чтобы изменить поле и событие, на которые будет реагировать v-model, можно воспользоваться специальным функционалом https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#model

Comment: Не совсем понял по данной ссылке что прописать необходимо.
Можите пример HTML кода инпута в компоненте и подключении показать в разрезе именно моей реализации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во Vuex я не зарывался. Тут же самое главное получить данные в родительском компоненте. Watcher только для того, чтобы показать изменения

```js
const Wrapper = Vue.component("Wrapper", {
  props: ["input_value"],
  template: `<div>
  <input class="input_text_1" :value="input_value" @input="$emit('input',$event.target.value)"/>
  </div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `<div>
  <Wrapper  v-model="message" :input_value="message"></Wrapper>
  </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      message: "111"
    };
  },
  watch: {
    message: function(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Но это все таки получается совсем другой подход - чем тот который я на скрине в доке показывал - верно?
В вашем примере добавлен атрибут @input - а в двунаправленных вычисляемых св-вах этого не демонстрируется + они и были нужны именно для того, как я понимаю что бы не прописывать все эти лишние сущности - или же я ошибаюсь?

Comment: в примерах, v-model используется на нативном тэге `input`, который автоматически генерирует события. Чего не делает Ваш компонент